# WCF service published by VS2010 on IIS7 won't show on IE

Tags: iis-7, wcf

I've published my WCF service using Visual Studio 2010 FTP option.

Now when I test it using localhost/MyService/MyService.svc it is throwing an error in IE:

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not FoundThe requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
```

What could be wrong if everything is set as default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have .NET Framework 3.5.1 Features installed.

Comment: Indeed I had to go to Windows features and turn on WCF! Also I run `"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\WFServicesReg.exe" /c`